# Android System Not Booting Correctly Inside Docker Container on Embedded System

Tags: android, docker, arm, embedded-linux

I am facing an issue with an Android system not working correctly, and I could really use your help. I am not an Android developer, so I am not very familiar with the Android OS or its inner workings. However, I am familiar with Linux systems, and I understand that Android is essentially an extra layer on top of Linux.

I am currently working on a project where I need to boot up a stock Android 12 version running inside a Docker container on an embedded system. The boards we are using have ArmV8 architecture and are running custom embedded Linux generated through Buildroot. I have two boards with very similar specs, using the same SoC (System on Chip), and the hardware is more or less identical, but the firmware is modified.

On one board, I can successfully boot up the Android in the container Docker image from the Linux terminal. The monitor (connected to the HDMI port on the device) displays a stock Android system as you would expect to see on a tablet, with icons, a desktop, etc. However, when I use the exact same Docker image on the other device (same hardware, different firmware), the system does not boot up successfully.

I am able to access the Android terminal of the system that does not boot to the Android "desktop," so the system is at least partially there. My theory is that the Android system is not booting up successfully, and many of the services do not get properly initialized. The first "hint" of this is the message "cmd: Can't find service: package." Inside the shell, I get this message if I try to run the "pm" command.

I have searched specifically for the "pm" error, and most of the discussions are around people booting up an Android emulator where it does not have time to fully boot. The suggested fix is to do a "cold boot" or somehow give the system more time to boot up. I am not exactly running an emulator, as this is running natively on an ARMV8 system, but it is running in a container.

I can run bugreportz and collect what I assume are the most relevant logs. I have attached the main log from the non-working system to this thread for reference. I have logs from both the working and non-working systems, so my next step would be to comb through the logs and try to identify the main differences that might point to why one system is working, and the other is not (e.g., error messages in the non-working system).

However, there is a lot to comb through here, and since I am not familiar with Android OS, I am not exactly sure what I am looking for yet or if I am even looking in the right place. I do see in the logs that many services do not show up in the logs in the non-working system. How do I debug why that might be?

Any help, tips, or links on how to narrow this down a bit so I am at least looking in the right area would be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Log Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cFHwqAMXZxpdePQ6zJ-2wFZ0bu-0R9df/view?usp=sharing

** UPDATE - After combing through the logs a lot more, I've discovered what looks like two different crashes in the above log. The first one looks to happen when its trying to display the boot animation. My understanding of SurfaceFlinger is that its used to send buffers of data to display to the window manager, so this seems like one problem at least. Could this crash be happening early enough that its preventing other services from loading?

```
05-08 05:21:34.489  1003    62   136 D BootAnimation: BootAnimationShownTiming start time: 310040ms
--------- beginning of crash
05-08 05:21:34.516  1000    61    61 F libc    : system/libfmq/include/fmq/MessageQueueBase.h:610: assertion "mReadPtr is null" failed
05-08 05:21:34.517  1000    61    61 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 61 (surfaceflinger), pid 61 (surfaceflinger)
05-08 05:21:34.663  root   191   191 I gsid    : no DSU: No such file or directory
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'rockchip/rk3588/rk3588:12/SQ3A.220605.009.B1/lisd12291420:userdebug/release-keys'
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2023-05-08 05:21:34.551424227+0000
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : Process uptime: 2s
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : Cmdline: /system/bin/surfaceflinger
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : pid: 61, tid: 61, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : uid: 1000
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
05-08 05:21:34.669  1000   158   158 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'system/libfmq/include/fmq/MessageQueueBase.h:610: assertion "mReadPtr is null" failed'
```

These are the only services running on the non-working.SurfaceFlinger is not one of them:

```
image:android.hardware.light.ILights/default
android.hardware.power.IPower/default
android.security.apc
android.security.authorization
android.security.compat
android.security.identity
android.security.legacykeystore
android.security.maintenance
android.security.metrics
android.service.gatekeeper.IGateKeeperService
android.system.keystore2.IKeystoreService/default
drm.drmManager
idmap
incident
installd
manager
media.extractor
media.metrics
stats
storaged
storaged_pri
suspend_control
suspend_control_internal
vold
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  Learnt a lot more about the android bootup in the process.  running bugreportz is great, but a simple "logcat" output to a file gives you pretty much what you need to see the startup of the android system.  For me, this was the issue:

```
 "05-09 00:15:04.048  1000   538   538 E ashmem  : Unable to open ashmem device /dev/ashmem41f198eb-231d-41bb-8928-f9dfb3712a2d (error = No such file or directory) and /dev/ashmem(error = No such file or directory)
05-09 00:15:04.048  1000   538   538 E FMQ     : mmap failed: 9
05-09 00:15:04.048  1000   538   538 F libc    : system/libfmq/include/fmq/MessageQueueBase.h:610: assertion "mReadPtr is null" failed
05-09 00:15:04.049  1000   538   538 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 538 (surfaceflinger), pid 538 (surfaceflinger)
```

There is a linux kernel module called "ashmem".  This module exists on the kernel on the working system, but not on the other system.  In other words, the linux kernels do not match and a requirement was missing